# Fixed percentage based grid with MiGLayout

Tags: java, javafx, miglayout

I am trying to create a grid with MiGLayout that is enforced on its children.  This means that if I insert a child into grid position (1,1) and the grid's size is [10%!] that this child must NOT be bigger and overlap other cells.  The child must be shrunk to fit the Grid cell.

This is what I have so far:

```
new MigPane("", "[5%!][20%!][5%!][65%!][5%!]", "[45%!][50%!][5%!]");
```

Now, I insert a big component (a picture that I have no control over) in Grid 1,1, like this:

```
migPane.add(myImageView, "cell 1 1, width 100%!");
```

However, that does not seem to restrict the ImageView at all.

How do I tell MiGLayout that I want "myImageView" to be put in grid 1,1 and size it to fit?  Is there a "fit" keyword? :)

Note that specifying anything with pixels/points/mm/cm/inches is NOT what I want.  My app always runs full-screen and must scale seamlessly (it is not a traditional form app, it is a video system using JavaFX).

Comment: It seems to be more related to ImageView in JavaFX not having proper min/pref/max sizes.  Wrapping it in a ScrollPane seems to get me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like percentages are supported, according to the [docs](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.html):

> Overrides the default size of the component that is set by the UI
>   delegate or by the developer explicitly on the component. The size is
>   specified as a BoundSize. See the Common Argument Types section above
>   for an explanation. Note that expressions is supported and you can for
>   instance set the size for a component with "width pref+10px" to make
>   it 10 pixels larger than normal or "width max(100, 10%)" to make it
>   10% of the container's width, but a maximum of 100 pixels.

Maybe try something like: `"width max(100%, 100%)"`.